# How to generate a control signal from the USB port?

Tags: ros, usb, libusb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello

I wish to add to my project with USB control. I want to ROS, with USB port write or read a voltage to put into operation a node or to kill him.

The question is: How I can do this task with the tools of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34764/how-to-generate-a-control-signal-from-the-usb-port?/) by [andresiguano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1921/andresiguano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need an MC like an arduino and then you can use rosserial.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2